# Speeding Up Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am using **BeautifulSoup** to parse several thousand websites within a for loop. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
def parse_decision(link):
    t1 = time.time()
    decisionpage = urllib.urlopen(link)
    t2 = time.time()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(decisionpage.read(), 'lxml')
    t3 = time.time()
    # ...
    # Parsing happens here and returns a pandas dataframe
```

Because the code takes forever to run I started investigating the cause and found that the time it takes for BeautifulSoup to read a decisionpage varies a lot. Here is a snippet of the seconds it takes to complete each step:

```
    Element | t2-t1  |  t3-t2
    1.      | 0.073  | 60.023
    2.      | 0.096  | 0.005
    3.      | 0.096  | 60.016
    4.      | 0.064  | 0.006
```

As one can see, roughly every second website takes **60 seconds** eventhough the websites are in the same format and contain roughly the same information.
Websites are court decisions similar to this one:
        http://www.nycourts.gov/reporter/3dseries/2003/2003_17749.htm

Does anyone have an idea why this **performance difference** exists and possibly how to overcome it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with BeautifulSoup? Considering the 60 seconds number, I'd be inclined to think the website you're scraping is throttling you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not `BeautifulSoup` which is slow, it's `decisionpage.read()`.

`urllib.urlopen` returns a socket object, actual http request happens at `.read()`. So your bottleneck if somewhere in the network: either your Internet connection or remote website is slow (or both).

Since you are I/O bound and have several thousand websites, you can speed up things significantly by running several threads parsing different websites at the same time.

Comment: Something like this https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html or more like python's multiprocessing module?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a paradoxical solution to your problem. It's pretty clear that the website you're attempting to scrape is throttling you.

I would suggest trying to respect their wishes and adding a pause between your requests. If you add `time.sleep(2)` (and `import time` to the top of the script) to the end of your loop, it may prevent you from being throttled for 60 seconds.

Experiment and see what number works best for you.

Comment: I totally missed that possibility. I will definitely try this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Yeah, BeautifulSoup is reasonably performant. I wouldn't recommend increasing the request rate, it's not nice and if you make too many requests at once to a court website they might decide to invite you over ;)

Answer (score 0):

While crawling large websites use threads: `concurrent.futures` or `threading`. In network I/O the thread `read()`ing the network resource spends most of its time sitting around waiting. This is a very befitting situation for employing concurrency.

Second, if you are not scraping specific stuff, just following anchor tags, **use regular expressions**. They are around 100 times faster than `HTMLParser` in my machine. The speedup will be significant.